# Generic HTTP upload tool

Tags: command-line, cross-platform, http, uploader

I am searching a tool for uploading files via HTTP.

For FTP there are several tools.

Required features:

- open source
- scriptable / CLI
- if the upload was successful, the files should get moved to a different directory
- should run on Linux/Windows/Mac.

Comment: Really, [tag:open-source]? Or just [tag:gratis]?

Comment: To be honest, I don't quire understand the question. FTP has only one purpose - to transfer files. HTTP is a completely different protocol. Are you looking for an upload library or component that you can include in some JS code that you are writing? I can't imagine a stand-alone HTTP upload program.

Comment: @Mawg, yes open source is a mandatory requirement.

Comment: Do you have a preferred language for it to be coded in?

Comment: @Mawg my preferred language is python.

Comment: curl, pycurl..?

Answer (score 1):

`if the upload was successful, the files should get moved to a different directory`. This probably is too specific for a tool to do. As you want it to be scriptable, why don't you do your custom python program? You already have an [http client](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) provided in Python (or [the requests library](https://realpython.com/python-requests/), which seems to have a nicer API).

Python already is:

- open source
- scriptable
- runs on linux/windows/mac

The part of moving your files when successful upload should be a one-liner in Python.

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line tool called [tbzuploader](https://github.com/tbz-pariv/tbzuploader)

> tbzuploader - Generic HTTP Uploading
>
> A lot of daily work is based on regular files.
>
> tbzuploader is a command line tool which detects uploadable files and
>   posts them via HTTP while conforming to the standardized HTTP Status
>   Codes. Upload Protocol
>
> tbzuploader conforms to the generally accepted upload protocol. 201
>   Created
>
> If the HTTP upload is successful, the server responds with "201
>   Created". The files will then be moved to a "done" directory. 400 Bad
>   Request
>
> If the HTTP upload is not successful and it is a client error (such as
>   wrong files or corrupted files), the server responds with "400 Bad
>   Request". The files will then be moved to a "failed" directory.
>
> In case you want to inform an admin, specify an email address which
>   gets notified in that case, because failed files won't be retried. 500
>   Internal Server Error and others
>
> If the HTTP upload was not successful (such as an login page, outage,
>   programming error or overload), the server responds with other status
>   codes (such as 500 Internal Server Error). tbzuploader will then retry
>   to post the files next time.
>
> Features
>
> pairs of arbitrary size (tuples, triplets, etc.)
>
> For example you have four files: a.pdf, a.xml, b.pdf, b.xml
>
> The first upload should take a.pdf and a.xml, and the second upload b.pdf and b.xml.
>           See the docs for --patterns.
>
> mail to admin if broken files are uploaded